# How to insert multiple rows into mysql using Codeigniter Rest Api

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a form with one add button. Next row will append whenever i click on add button and all entered data should store into database. I can do for single record but unable to do with multiple records. Please provide any help for my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use $this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $dataArray)

Comment: show us your code for insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->db->insert_batch() is used for bulk insert.

Example of how it works (assuming I have a series of 20 records to insert) :

```
array_push($newRecords, array(
   "property1" => 1
   "property2" => "two"
));
//...
array_push($newRecords, array(
   "property1" => 20
   "property2" => "twenty"
));

$this->db->insert_batch("tableName", $newRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to do this:

you can put insert code in foreach

```
foreach($variable as $key=>$value){
  $this->db->insert('table name',array('fieldname'=>'values'));
}
```

this above method called every time for every loop

or used the batch methods

```
$this->db->insert_batch('table name',$dataArray);
```

this above method will called one time only.

Comment: I have tried this one. But still i am unable to insert values. Can you please help with any example for it?

Comment: which method you have try?

Comment: I have tried insert_batch() but i was getting error as DB query builder on postman.